# How to import jsonLogic into a Svelte component

Tags: javascript, svelte, jsonlogic

What is the syntax to import and use [jsonLogic](https://github.com/jwadhams/json-logic-js/) within [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/)?

Answer (score 0):

Using jsonLogic in Svelte requires no modifications to the jsonLogic javascript, simply import and use like so:

```
import jsonLogic from './logic.js';  // where logic.js is saved locally in your Svelte public folder
let objJL = jsonLogic;  // assign the jsonLogic instance to a Svelte component variable (I simply named mine objJL)
objJL.apply({"==" : [1,1] }); // try out jsonLogic (this is a true condition)
```

Here it is in action using the Svelte REPL:
https://svelte.dev/repl/a208faeafa4a4615bb5100015d4b1f91